# why JInternalFrame remove all of the other component

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe

i finished from adding the `JInternalFrame` inside my `JFrame` and the way frame is added is to click over the `JMenuItem` icon and this is goes fine but when ever the frame is added the old component are removed and white color shows up. what i am trying to do is to set fix `JInternalFrame`  location with the other component with out effect other component

the code for JInternalFrame

```
    package animeaidvlcj;

import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;


/* Used by InternalFrameDemo.java. */
public class MyInternalFrame extends JInternalFrame {
    static int openFrameCount = 0;
    static final int xOffset = 0, yOffset = 25;

    public MyInternalFrame() {
        super("Document #" + (++openFrameCount), 
              true, //resizable
              true, //closable
              true, //maximizable
              true);//iconifiable

        //...Create the GUI and put it in the window...

        //...Then set the window size or call pack...
        setSize(300,300);

        //Set the window's location.
        setLocation(xOffset*openFrameCount, yOffset*openFrameCount);
    }
}
```

the Action code

```
 Action newAction = new AbstractAction("New", newIcon) {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            desktop = new JDesktopPane();
            createFrame();
            setContentPane(desktop);
            desktop.setDragMode(JDesktopPane.OUTLINE_DRAG_MODE);
        }
    };
```

create method

```
protected void createFrame() {
    MyInternalFrame frame = new MyInternalFrame();
    frame.setVisible(true); //necessary as of 1.3
    desktop.add(frame);
    try {
        frame.setSelected(true);
    } catch (java.beans.PropertyVetoException e) {}
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "why JInternalFrame remove all of the other component"

Well First look at this code in your `Action`

```
desktop = new JDesktopPane();
createFrame();
setContentPane(desktop);  <== this line in particular
```

You are setting the content pane of the frame (assuming `setContenPane()` is calling the class frame) with the `desktop`, which will remove the previous content pane, which holds all your components. So the only thing that will appear is the `desktop` along with the new `JInternalFrame`.

Unless you are creating a [Multiple Document Interface (MDI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_document_interface), which desktop panes and internal frames are mainly for, I suggest you just use a `JDialog` and forget the `DesktopPane`.  You can see [How to use Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html). It's pretty much the same as creating a `JFrame`, except you have the option of [modality](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/modality-137604.html).

Comment: i am trying to use other frame for vlcj so the Other options is bad idea  but can i replace the setContentPane(desktop) to other like jpanel

Comment: Do both frames need to be accessible at the same time? Like when the new window is open, do want to be able to access the main frame?

Comment: yes absolutely.but i not sure because i think vlcj can run in the other frame while i am using the main frame

Comment: You can just create a Modelesss `JDialog` You create it just like a frame. The only difference is that it won't be contained inside of the main frame. But you you do want to use the jdeesktoppane with the internal frame, then you are going to have to restructure your application to built around the desktop pane. You can just switch content panes with the frame and expect the components on the original content pane to still show. For the dialog, just `setModel(false)`.

Comment: can JDialog embedded to JFrame

Comment: No. If you read my comment, it says that it won't be contained inside of the frame. If you want that feature, like I said, you will have to restructure your application around that desktop pane.